# function createIdentityMatrix(a,b)

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, matrix

I need to create function, that is creating something like this:

```
createIdentityMatrix(4,4) => [ [1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1] ];
```

I did something like this:

```
var nextTab = []
var tab = [nextTab]
function createIdentityMatrix(a,b) {
for (var i = 0; i < a; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < b; j++) {
    if (i === j) {
      // secondTab.push([tab.push(1)])
      tab.push([nextTab.push(1)])
    }else {
      tab.push([nextTab.push(0)])
      // secondTab.push([tab.push(0)])
    }
  }return nextTab
}
}
console.log(createIdentityMatrix(4,4));
```

As you can see it's not working, the same if I do `return tab`. I know that return statement is closing the loop...

So how to create a new array, after four loops, and push it once bigger?

Comment: I just try few things... this my last version of code. It's not looking good, but I was looking for sollution. What do you suggest ?

Comment: What is `tab.push([nextTab.push(1)])` supposed to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to do something like this

```
function createIdentityMatrix(size) {
const matrix = [];
for (let i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    const line = [];
    for (let j = 0; j < size; j++) {
        line[j] = i === j ? 1 : 0;
    }
    matrix.push(line);
}

return matrix;
```

}

Comment: Yes, It's much more closer to plain javaScript. 
I need to have

function createIdentityMatrix(size, sizeTwo)

And create this in plain javaScript

Comment: line[j] = i === j ? 1 : 0;

What's do this ? Can you explain ?

Comment: it's like if the statement is true (i === j) then set the value to 1 else set it to 0.

Answer (score 3):

You could check if the index of the outer array is equal to the index of the inner array, then return `1`, otherwise `0`.

```js
function createIdentityMatrix(a, b) {
    return Array.from(
        { length: a },
        (_, i) => Array.from({ length: b }, (_, j) => +(i === j))
    );
}

console.log(createIdentityMatrix(4, 4));
```

Comment: Nice it's working well, but I need to do this using 2 loops... I didn't know that I can create code like that.

Answer (score 0):

It might be more elegant with the use of functional programming:

```
const identity = (width, height) => 
 Array.from({length: width}, (_, row) => 
   Array.from({length: height}, (_, col) => +(row === col))
 );
```

Comment: Can I do this using 2 for loops ? I mean plain JavaScript - I need to understand my own code, and I'm beginner.